# Deleting QWinWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-mfc-migration

I am using mfc to Qt migration and I am showing Qt dialogs in my Mfc app. 
Is it Ok to deleteLater QWinWidget in its winEvent handler?
The thing is that I want all of my open Qt dialogs in My Mfc application
to be automatically deleted when the main mfc window is closed.
Since WM_DESTROY will be sent for all child windows ( and the Qt widgets too)
So I added the following code in QwinWidget winEvent handler :

```
QWinWidget::winEvent(MSG * message, long * result)
       {
                 ........
                 if(message->message == WM_DESTROY )
                     deleteLater();
                 return false;
       }
```

Can someone comment this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Strictly regarding the safety of the `deleteLater()` call, it is usually safe to do inside a function running inside that class.  The object won't be deleted until control is back into the event loop functions.  The only potential problems I can see involve multi-threaded code, which likely wouldn't be the case for a widget with it's event handlers.